# How to detect collision to stop player movement in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner and I want to know how to make player stops movement when hitting an obstacle.
I tried this code but it shows that it's deprecated

```
public class Collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMove move;

    void onCollisionEnter (Collision info)
    {
        if (info.Collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            move.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I tried this code but it shows that it's deprecated* - might you please [edit] your question to explain what, exactly, is deprecated?  Any error messages or warnings would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with methods in Unity, they start with an Uppercase.

`OnCollisionEnter` should start with an Uppercase to be recognized by Unity as the method called once per collision.

As `scopolamin` said, don't call your class `Collision` : you'd better rename it as well as your file, your **class name** and your **file name** must match in order to inherit from a MonoBehaviour.

I assume `PlayerMove` is the script you use as a character controller. Be sure your variable `move` has the right script attached.

Answer (score 1):

You named your class `Collision`. The parameter `info` in the OnCollisionEnter method doesn't use `UnityEngine.Collision` but your own `Collision` class.

Change your class name `Collision` to something else:

`public class` **Collision** `: MonoBehaviour`

`public class MyCollision : MonoBehaviour`